# Qt Unsupported Makefile Generator / Qt 6.60 / Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, qt

I'm trying to add Qt 6.60 to Visual Studio 2022.  In particular, I'm modifying the Options for Qt and it is failing.

[image: Visual Studio 2022 / Tools-Options]

When I select `qmake.exe`, Visual Studio responds with:

[image: Error]

I've searched the Qt bug support page and don't see any mention of this issue.  There's not(?) a newer version of VS.  Should I downgrade my Qt and try again?

Comment: You should download the correct Qt version for MSVC, not for MinGW as you can't mix different them when using c++

Comment: Thanks!  I was blindly following a video for installation and didn't see the subtle difference.  Makes sense to me.  I pointed VS ad MSVC qmake.exe and was successful.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @[chehrlic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13043272/chehrlic)!

I was blindly following a video for installation and didn't see the subtle difference between `MSVC` and `MingGW`. Makes sense to me.

I pointed **VS** at **MSVC** `qmake.exe` and was successful.